# How to update IntelliJ IDEA's cached information on projects when they are moved to other location?

Tags: caching, intellij-idea, metadata, projects-and-solutions

There are number of IntelliJ IDEA projects under some path on a disk. It saves some metadata (actually a lot) at `home/.IdeaIC11`. Is it possible somehow to tell IDEA that all projects have been moved to another location and have its metadata cache rebuilt/updated?

Comment: Caches are updated automatically when you open a project from the new location.

Comment: There are lot of projects under the same location (in different sub directories). I don't wont to open each of them manually...

Comment: You don't have to. When you need to open them, caches will be updated. There is no way to trigger caches update without opening a project.

Comment: You can open them only when you need to do some changes. It isn't necessary update metadata for all projects at same time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to update metadata but the easiest way (but little bit slow) is detele metadata. When you open project again IDEA will rebuilt metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't answer my question. I know about these two directories (`config` and `system`). A grep for the path where all IntelliJ IDEA project are returns tons of results. Is there a way telling IDEA that the location has been moved and that it should update its metadata accordingly?

Comment: Ah sorry. I don't know how to update metadata but the easiest way (but little bit slow) is detele metadata. When you open project again IDEA will rebuilt metadata.